# Replace instance of item in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with strings if the string is `foo` I wish to replace it with `bar`.

I could do a for-loop:

```
for (var i = carpeDiem.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(carpeDiem[i] === '\n'){
        carpeDiem[i] = '<br \>'
    }
};
```

But is there a nicer way to do it. I only need to support modern browsers.

Comment: If it works why bother changing it?

Comment: Why not loop through the array and use `string.replace()`?

Comment: @Andreas To futher my skills and to make the code more readable for other developers. (and my future self)

Comment: @stevenw00 like this:   carpeDiem[i].replace('\n', '<br \>')

Comment: _"...make the code more readable..."_ After reading it the first time I know exactly what the code is going to do. Fewer lines of code doesn't always mean better readability :) If you really want to change it, you could use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or, if you don't want to modify `carpeDiem`, [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: the replace would do foos -> bars as well, even tho for the \n it's probably a good thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbJqeq

```
var carpeDiem = ['\n', '<br />', '\n', '<br />'];

carpeDiem = carpeDiem.map(function(i) { 
    return i.replace('\n', '<br />') 
});

console.log(carpeDiem) // ['<br />', '<br />', '<br />', '<br />'];
```

Comment: why not just `carpeDiem.map(function(i) { return i.replace('\n', '<br />'); });`?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

This is the thing for you, it's ES6 so should work at least in FF, but there are polyfills for it (that are probably doing the same as your code above).

Comment: _"The find() method returns a value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function."_ How is this supposed to satisfy the requirement - replace all strings "x" with string "y"?

Comment: array.find((s)=>{s == 'foo' && s = bar});

Comment: So you're going to misuse `.find()` to replace the string passed as parameter `s` with `"bar"` if it matches `"foo"`. This won't change the array! And even if it would change the value in the array it will only change the **first** occurance.

Comment: I wouldn't call it misuse. Yes I use closure and side effect, but it's valid and does exactly what the OP's for loop.